# How can I create a JAR file with PDF, Excel, and db files inside it, and how can i reach those?

Tags: java, windows, pdf, jar

I have developed an application that need to have PDF files, database and Excel files inside. I now want to make a JAR file of my progam so that others can use it. When the program starts, it creates a folder on the desktop that contains the PDF, Excel, and db files. The user can then, if necessary, modify the Excel file manually.

Right now, I can create a folder with the files and put it on the desktop, but only in NetBeans. I can not do that with the jar file of my program.

I need to know how I can reach these files and if I can possibly "pack in" these files into a jar file?

I use Java and NetBeans. The operating system is Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can build a zip file with jar, PDF, excel and DB files inside and let your users unzip it in application home directory

Comment: It should be noted that a .jar file is just a different extension on a .zip file. It sounds like you might want an executable jar, which is a little more specialized.